# Output event data in Python 3.6 AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I am trying to output an event called sheetID in a AWS Lambda Python function, but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Here is a code snippet:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.run()
    return { "Message": "Scrape function ran correctly!" }

class Scraper():
    def __init__(self):
        log.debug("Starting scraper...")
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        credentials = sac.from_json_keyfile_name('src/h9d7246486f2.json', scope)

        log.debug("Authorizing gspread...")
        self.gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
        self.spreadsheet = self.gc.open_by_key(event['sheetID'])
...
```

This is the line with the issue:

```
self.spreadsheet = self.gc.open_by_key(event['sheetID'])
```

which previously had a static Google Sheet name

```
self.spreadsheet = self.gc.open("CorStats")
```

A test Lambda function works fine with event data, but not sure whether the format part can or should be used in the function above.

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['key1'], 
                                    event['key3'])  
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```

Here is the error log:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "name 'event' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/src/scrape_lambda.py",
      18,
      "lambda_handler",
      "scraper = Scraper()"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/src/scrape_lambda.py",
      30,
      "__init__",
      "self.spreadsheet = self.gc.open_by_key(event['sheetID'])"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you share the error message you're receiving?

Comment: @maafk Error log added. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need include event in the `__init__` method, e.g. `def __init__(self, event):`, then instantiate it with `scraper = Scraper(event)`.

It might be cleaner to do `def __init__(self, sheet_id)`, then do `scraper = Scraper(event['sheetID'))` and `self.spreadsheet = self.gc.open_by_key(sheet_id)`. This way, you have uncoupled the `Scraper` class from the lambda event and can test it separately.